# json.Unmarshal file data works but json.NewDecoder().Decode() does not

Tags: json, go, decode

The following correctly unmarshals the struct:

```
func foo() {
  d, err := os.ReadFile("file.json")

  var t T
  if err := json.Unmarshal(d, &t); err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
}
```

but this doesn't work and throws a bunch of a classic JSON parsing errors i.e. `EOF`, `unexpected token 't'`, etc.

```
func foo() {
  f, err := os.Open("file.json")
  
  var t T
  if err := json.NewDecoder(f).Decode(&t); err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
}
```

Any idea why? The `os.File` or `[]byte` is used in two goroutines at once, and the JSON is of the following structure (with some fields omitted):

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "field": "stuff",
      "num": 123,
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

Comment: Just had a thought, does `decode` scan the file and I have to reset the scanner position?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The `os.File` or `[]byte` is used in two goroutines at once...

That's the issue. `os.File` has an internal file pointer, a position where the next read happens. If 2 unrelated entities keep reading from it, they will likely not read overlapping data. Bytes read by the first entity will not be repeated for the second.

Also, `os.File` is not safe for concurrent use (the documentation doesn't state explicitly that it's safe): calling its methods from multiple, concurrent goroutines may result in a data race.

When you pass a `[]byte` to multiple functions / goroutines which read "from it", there's no shared pointer or index variable. Each function / goroutine will maintain its index, separately, and reading a variable from multiple goroutines is OK (which in this case would be the (fields of the) slice header and the slice elements).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was looking at the decode source but must not have looked far enough to realize that it reads the file (though I probably could've intuited that if I were smarter).